# Django South migration is throwing an error 'module' object has no attribute 'SET_NULL'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-south

I just generated the migration scripts through `./manage.py schemamigration --auto` and ran it.  I get the following error.  I am stumped as to what it could mean.  I have been using SET_NULL for a while now.  So this is something new that didn't occur earlier.  Any idea what could be wrong?

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 16, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/vivekv/.environments/fantain/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/init.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/vivekv/.environments/fantain/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/init.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/vivekv/.environments/fantain/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.dict)
  File "/home/vivekv/.environments/fantain/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/vivekv/.environments/fantain/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/schemamigration.py", line 111, in handle
    old_orm = last_migration.orm(),
  File "/home/vivekv/.environments/fantain/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/utils/init.py", line 62, in method
    value = function(self)
  File "/home/vivekv/.environments/fantain/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/base.py", line 432, in orm
    return FakeORM(self.migration_class(), self.app_label())
  File "/home/vivekv/.environments/fantain/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/orm.py", line 48, in FakeORM
    _orm_cache[args] = _FakeORM(*args)

  File "/home/vivekv/.environments/fantain/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/orm.py", line 134, in init
    self.retry_failed_fields()
  File "/home/vivekv/.environments/fantain/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/orm.py", line 377, in retry_failed_fields
    fname, modelname, e
ValueError: Cannot successfully create field 'winner' for model 'match': 'module' object has no attribute 'SET_NULL'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK This is not a valid question.  I am embarrassed to admit I made a small tweak on the migration script that caused the problem.  Please ignore this question - seems like I dont have a way to delete a question I had asked!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35962023/1552520)

Short answer: use `models.SET_NULL` instead of `"SET_NULL"`.
You need to replace this in all migrations which have `b"SET_NULL"`